# Pre get posts where template is not equal to one specified?

Tags: page-template, pre-get-posts

I'm trying to not show certain posts in the admin area based on the page template. Here is what I have so far:

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'hide_some_posts' );

function hide_some_posts( $query ) {
    global $pagenow;
    $myHiddenPosts = array('10667');
    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php') {
       $query->set( 'post__not_in', $myHiddenPosts );
    }
}
```

This works perfectly based on page ID, but I'm looking to do this based on the page template instead. I came across this:

```
    $query->set('meta_key','_wp_page_template');
    $query->set('meta_value', 'page-some-template.php'); //Change filename to yours
```

But how can I make it so that only works for including. I would like to not include pages based on the template.

Any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you using `pre_get_posts`?  The title of the question might need adjusting.  Are you trying to add a condition to `hide_some_posts()` that checks the template in use for that page?

Comment: @jdm2112 Yes trying to hide some posts that check the template in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `meta_query` to pass meta query arguments.

```
add_action('parse_query', 'se334731_filter_admin_post_list');

function se334731_filter_admin_post_list( $query )
{
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( is_admin()  && $screen->post_type == 'page'  && $screen->base == 'edit' )
    {
        $query->query_vars['meta_query'][] = [
            'relation' => 'OR',
            [
                'key' => '_wp_page_template',
                'value'    => 'page-some-template.php',
                'compare'  => '!=',
                //'value'    => array( 'page-some-template.php' ),
                //'compare'  => 'NOT IN'
            ],
            [
                'key' => '_wp_page_template',
                'compare'  => 'NOT EXISTS'
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

These changes will not affect the summary of the number of posts (*all*, *published*, *trashed*) above table. To correct the displayed number of posts, use the `wp_count_posts` filter.

[Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) you can read more about *Custom field parameters*.

Comment: Sadly this didn't work. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: I wrote `meta_key` insted of `key`.

Comment: How can be be done for multiple page templates?

Comment: Comment out first lines with `value` and `compare` and uncomment the next two lines.